# Why would ExecuteNonQuery return -1 for an INSERT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am investigating a situation in an application where `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` was called and returned a value of -1.

The command is a simple string containing an `INSERT` query - no parameters, etc. just simply:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3... ) 
VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

which is inserting just one row.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)...

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

However, this being an `INSERT` statement, the above remark doesn't tie in. Interestingly, the row was successfully inserted.

A bit of logic in the code tries to detect if the insert failed, ( -1 is interpreted as failure) then it attempts to "repair" the connection (basically just closes it and opens it again) before trying the `INSERT`. The second time around, it successfully inserted the row and returned the correct code - the result being that I now have two identical records in the database.

So my question is - what would cause an `ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT...")` to successfully insert the record, return -1, but when the `SqlConnection` was closed and reopened, return the correct value on retry?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: The remarks on your link says "If no statements are detected that contribute to the count, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1"  Do the column names in table match the names in the INSERT?  Does table name match?  Are you connected to correct Server?  Check connection string.

Comment: @DaleK - no triggers in the database at all

Comment: @jdweng - yep, everything matches. I must assume the connection to the server is correct as other queries run during the running of the application at the time did run successfully, including several calls to this same function. This appears to be an isolated incident. There is no transaction to roll back and the row was successfully inserted, which implies the the connection was to the correct server.

Comment: Would you not consider try/catch to check for errors instead of checking for -1 returned?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return -1 if `SET NOCOUNT ON` has been previously executed on the same connection.

Comment: What is the value of `SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) & 512 FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'user options'` and have you executed `SET NOCOUNT ON` anywhere?

Comment: "A bit of logic in the code tries to detect if the insert failed, ( -1 is interpreted as failure) then it attempts to "repair" the connection (basically just closes it and opens it again) before trying the INSERT." this is flat-out wrong. If the insert failed then an error would be thrown. The only time you should do this is if you expect non-error situations where the insert doesn't happen, such as server-side validation. `-1` just indicates the server did not tell you how many rows were affected. Closing and reopening the connection is unlikely to fix an error even if there was one.

Comment: Yes I understand it's wrong. Unfortunately this is pretty old code, and right now I'm trying to understand what did happen that could cause this temporary issue.

Comment: OK how about you actually answer the questions I asked.